# problem text not updating after vue 3 upgrade

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component that I'm trying to rewrite for vue 3, more specifically, using their new setup script so the code is a bit cleaner looking, here is what it looks like currently.

```js
export default {
    name: "typeWriter",
    data: () => {
        return {
            typeValue: "",
            typeStatus: false,
            displayTextArray: ['Art', 'Science', 'Math', 'Everything'],
            typingSpeed: 70,
            erasingSpeed: 70,
            newTextDelay: 1000,
            displayTextArrayIndex: 0,
            charIndex: 0,
        };
    },
    created() {
        setTimeout(this.typeText, this.newTextDelay + 200);
    },
    methods: {
        typeText() {
            if (this.charIndex < this.displayTextArray[this.displayTextArrayIndex].length) {
                if (!this.typeStatus) {
                    this.typeStatus = true;
                }

                this.typeValue += this.displayTextArray[this.displayTextArrayIndex].charAt(this.charIndex);
                this.charIndex++;

                setTimeout(this.typeText, this.typingSpeed);
            } else {
                this.typeStatus = false;

                // stop the typing once we hit the last thing we wish to type.
                if (this.displayTextArrayIndex + 1 >= this.displayTextArray.length) {
                    return
                }

                setTimeout(this.eraseText, this.newTextDelay);
            }
        },
        eraseText() {
            if (this.charIndex > 0) {
                if (!this.typeStatus) {
                    this.typeStatus = true;
                }

                this.typeValue = this.displayTextArray[this.displayTextArrayIndex].substring(0, this.charIndex - 1);
                this.charIndex -= 1;

                setTimeout(this.eraseText, this.erasingSpeed);
            } else {
                this.typeStatus = false;
                this.displayTextArrayIndex++;

                setTimeout(this.typeText, this.typingSpeed + 1000);
            }
        },
    },
};
```

Here is the new vue 3 code using `<script setup lang="ts">`

```js
let typeValue = ""
let typeStatus = false
let displayTextArray = ['Art', 'Science', 'Math', 'Everything']
let typingSpeed = 70
let erasingSpeed = 70
let newTextDelay = 1000
let displayTextArrayIndex = 0
let charIndex = 0

setTimeout(typeText, newTextDelay);

function typeText() {
    if (charIndex < displayTextArray[displayTextArrayIndex].length) {
        if (!typeStatus) {
            typeStatus = true;
        }

        typeValue += displayTextArray[displayTextArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
        charIndex++;

        setTimeout(typeText, typingSpeed);
    } else {
        typeStatus = false;

        // stop the typing once we hit the last thing we wish to type.
        if (displayTextArrayIndex + 1 >= displayTextArray.length) {
            return
        }

        setTimeout(eraseText, newTextDelay);
    }
}

function eraseText() {
    if (charIndex > 0) {
        if (!typeStatus) {
            typeStatus = true;
        }

        typeValue = displayTextArray[displayTextArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1);
        charIndex -= 1;

        setTimeout(eraseText, erasingSpeed);
    } else {
        typeStatus = false;
        displayTextArrayIndex++;

        setTimeout(typeText, typingSpeed + 1000);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm hitting is, the vue 2 code it'll correctly update a div with the value in `typeValue`, the new vue 3 code is **not** updating the div, I added a console.log and can see that the code is indeed firing and working, the div just isn't recognizing this change in `typeValue` and I'm completely lost on why that is.

I'm still new to vue 3, so maybe I missed something, but this looks right to me so I'm lost on why the div isn't updating like it used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make your data reactive with [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref):

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    let typeValue = ref("")
    let typeStatus = false
    let displayTextArray = ['Art', 'Science', 'Math', 'Everything']
    let typingSpeed = 70
    let erasingSpeed = 70
    let newTextDelay = 1000
    let displayTextArrayIndex = ref(0)
    let charIndex = 0
    
    setTimeout(typeText, newTextDelay);
    
    function typeText() {
      if (charIndex < displayTextArray[displayTextArrayIndex.value].length) {
        if (!typeStatus) {
          typeStatus = true;
        }
        typeValue.value += displayTextArray[displayTextArrayIndex.value].charAt(charIndex);
        charIndex++;
        setTimeout(typeText, typingSpeed);
      } else {
        typeStatus = false;
        if (displayTextArrayIndex.value + 1 >= displayTextArray.length) {
          return
        }
        setTimeout(eraseText, newTextDelay);
      }
    }

    function eraseText() {
      if (charIndex > 0) {
        if (!typeStatus) {
          typeStatus = true;
        }
        typeValue.value = displayTextArray[displayTextArrayIndex.value].substring(0, charIndex - 1);
        charIndex -= 1;
        setTimeout(eraseText, erasingSpeed);
      } else {
        typeStatus = false;
        displayTextArrayIndex.value++;
        setTimeout(typeText, typingSpeed + 1000);
      }
    }
    return {
      typeValue, eraseText, typeText
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input type="text" :value="typeValue" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I was really close and totally forgot about ```ref()```.